# Intuitively, why do we choose the smallest neighborhood to prove that the intersection of finitely many open subsets is open?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Theorem: Show that the intersection of any finite collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ is open.
I'm having trouble conceptually understanding the proof. It states: Let $\{O_1,O_2,...,O_n\}$ be a finite collection of open sets. Now, if $z_o\in \cap O_k ,\quad \forall k \in \{1,..,n\}$ this implies that $z_o$ is an element of each of the open sets. By definition, we know that $\exists$ a neighborhood of $z_o$,  $D(z_o,r_k)\subseteq O_k$, for all k. Now here is the kicker, we are in search for a single neighborhood that is contained in every open set, so we take the smallest one, $r=min\{r_1,r_2,...,r_n\}$. So how does taking the smallest one guarantee that it is going to be contained in the intersection and therefore in every open set?

Comment: Small typo: it should be $r=\min\{r_1, r_2, . . . , r_n\}$.

Comment: Because the smallest one is contained in all the others....

Comment: Because if $r<s,$ then $B(a,r) \subset B(a,s).$ That is the entirety of what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at an example. Take $O_1$ to be the circle centered at the origin with radius $1$, and $O_2$ the circle centered at the origin with radius $10$, and take our $z_0$ to be the origin. Then $r_1=1$ and $r_2=10$.

The point is we have to take $D(z_0, r_1)$ rather than $D(z_0, r_2)$ - if we pick the latter, then that disc "spills out" of $O_1$. The point is:

- If $r\le r_1$, then $D(z_0, r)\subseteq O_1$.
- If $r\le r_2$, then $D(z_0, r)\subseteq O_2$.

And this will be true in general. So, if we want $D(z_0, r)\subseteq O_k$ for *every* $k$, we need $r$ to be such that $$r\le r_1, r_2, . . . , r_n.$$ Taking $r=\min\{r_1, r_2, . . . , r_n\}$ does the job.

Comment: I see, this really helped. Thanks!